# Trying to install svgpathtools on Python 3.8 but is is trying to compile SciPy from source

Tags: python, windows

I installed `svgpathtools` on my Win7 desktop PC at home and it installed with pip without any drama. When I try to the same on my Win7 laptop away from home it tries to compile SciPy from source. First it said my Visual Studio was too old, so I installed the same version I had at home. Then it wants a Fortran compiler and also Cython & Pythran.

I know for sure my machine at home doesn't' have Fortran. I last used it 40 years ago at university. So I am assuming it didn't compile it from source when I installed `svgpathtools` only a month or two ago at home. Both machines run Python 3.8

Is SciPy a recent addition to `svgpathtools` or is there normally a precompiled version installed by pip?

I did `pip3 install svgpathtools` and expected it to work on my laptop as it did on my desktop. Both are Win7 machines running Python3.8.

On my Laptop I get this:

```
Collecting svgpathtools
  Using cached svgpathtools-1.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (22 kB)
Collecting numpy (from svgpathtools)
  Using cached numpy-1.24.4-cp38-cp38-win32.whl.metadata (5.6 kB)
Collecting svgwrite (from svgpathtools)
  Using cached svgwrite-1.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting scipy (from svgpathtools)
  Using cached scipy-1.10.1.tar.gz (42.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ?─> [37 lines of output]
      + meson setup --prefix=C:\Users\ChrisP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32 C:\Users\ChrisP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ms2m88hq\scipy_b7f99b4cab1644edb6b1688ed268a
pData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ms2m88hq\scipy_b7f99b4cab1644edb6b1688ed268ad93\.mesonpy-euyc2m8v\build --native-file=C:\Users\ChrisP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ms2m88hq\scipy_b
ed268ad93\.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.2.3
      Source dir: C:\Users\ChrisP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ms2m88hq\scipy_b7f99b4cab1644edb6b1688ed268ad93
      Build dir: C:\Users\ChrisP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ms2m88hq\scipy_b7f99b4cab1644edb6b1688ed268ad93\.mesonpy-euyc2m8v\build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: SciPy
      Project version: 1.10.1
      Activating VS 16.11.31
      C compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 19.29.30152 "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30152 for x64")
      C linker for the host machine: link link 14.29.30152.0
      C++ compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 19.29.30152 "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30152 for x64")
      C++ linker for the host machine: link link 14.29.30152.0
      Cython compiler for the host machine: cython (cython 0.29.36)
      Host machine cpu family: x86_64
      Host machine cpu: x86_64
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-but-set-variable: NO
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-function: NO
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-conversion: NO
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-misleading-indentation: NO
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types: NO
      Library m found: NO

      ..\..\meson.build:63:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['ifort'], ['gfortran'], ['flang'], ['pgfortran'], ['g95']]
      The following exception(s) were encountered:
      Running `ifort --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `ifort -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `gfortran --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `gfortran -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `flang --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `flang -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `pgfortran --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `pgfortran -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `g95 --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `g95 -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

      A full log can be found at C:\Users\ChrisP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ms2m88hq\scipy_b7f99b4cab1644edb6b1688ed268ad93\.mesonpy-euyc2m8v\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
?─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```